# how to tag random friend upload picture

Tags: facebook, api, tags

I wanted to know how I tagged random friends when I bring up an image with this code
This code opens an album and uploads an image.

If someone here can help me what to change, and add code"

Thank you

```
<?php
    require 'facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '',
        'secret' => '',
        'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($user) {
        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

        //Create an album
        $album_details = array(
            'message'=> 'Album desc',
            'name'=> 'Album name'
        );
        $create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

        //Get album ID of the album you've just created
        $album_uid = $create_album['id'];

        //Upload a photo to album of ID...
        $photo_details = array(
            'message'=> 'Photo message'
        );
        $file='images/logo.jpg'; //Example image file
        $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);

        $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Why would you tag “random” friends on photos? Just FYI, Facebook does not like it if people are tagged in photos that aren’t _real_ “photos”, but rather composite images or something completely different with maybe not even actual people in it. They say somewhere in the docs that your app might be taken the ability to tag people in photos if such behavior occurs to often.

Comment: Yeah I know but still,
Want it to automatically tagged

Comment: Well then, read up on how tagging via API works in the docs please. And if you have _specific_ questions, come back here.

Answer (score 0):

According [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags) i added code to you script

```
<?php
define('COUNT_FRIENDS', '10');

require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '',
    'secret' => '',
    'cookie' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

    //Create an album
    $album_details = array(
        'message'=> 'Album desc',
        'name'=> 'Album name'
    );
    $create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

    //Get album ID of the album you've just created
    $album_uid = $create_album['id'];

    //Upload a photo to album of ID...
    $photo_details = array(
        'message'=> 'Photo message'
    );
    $file='images/logo.jpg'; //Example image file
    $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);

    $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);

    /*
    *  Make tags on photo
    */
    $photo_id = $upload_photo['id'];

    /*
    * Get friends info from FB
    */
    $result = $fb_app->api('/me/friends');

    $friend_uids = array();
    if($result && $result['data']){
       foreach($result['data'] as $friend){
          $friend_uids[] = $friend['id'];
       }
    }

    /*
    * Choose random friends UID's
    */
    $rand_keys = array_rand($friend_uids, COUNT_FRIENDS);
    foreach($rand_keys as $key){
       $friends[] = $friend_uids[$key];
    }

    foreach($friends as $friend_uid){
        $tag_params = array(
            'to'       => $friend_uid,
            'tag_text' => 'Sample tag text',
            'x'        => 0,
            'y'        => 0
        );
        $result = $facebook->api('/' . $photo_id . '/tags', 'POST', $tag_params);
    }
}
?>
```

Just implement function "getRandomFriends()" that returns list of UID's.

Comment: I added the code to select random friends. Insert into const 'COUNT_FRIENDS' your value.